# Why there are different result in this program aren't temp=*a and *a= temp same thing?

Tags: c

I was going through udemy course of C and found this problem isn't both declaring is same ?? If yes why answers are different

Source Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int *a, int *b){
    int temp;
   temp =*a;       // This works
   //*a = temp;    // This does not work?
    *a = *b;
    *b=temp;
}

int main()
{
    int x=100, y=400;
    printf("before swapping x is %d and y is %d\n",x,y);
    swap(&x,&y);
        printf("after swapping x is %d and y is %d",x,y);
return 0;
}
```

Why do I get different results from `temp=*a` compared to `*a=temp`?

Comment: Every time pictures of code are posted or linked on this site, a kitten dies. Questionable sample code should be copied, pasted, and formatted *verbatim*, to support your questions concerning said-same.

Comment: @WhozCraig: My daughter wants two Birman kittens - this goes some way in explaining the cost.

Comment: I think it's best as it is free and no adds

Comment: @HrithikAgrawal, please read the help text on how to post questions, here. There is no reason at all not to post the source code directly in your question.

Comment: Posting code as text is also for free and has no adds.

Comment: @Bathsheba Mine wants an Ocicat, but I've been avoiding telling her of the species carnage that ensues seemingly daily due to picture code posts.

Comment: Programming Language operations aren't like normal operations you do in school. In school, `x=5` and `5=x` are basically the same thing. In programming languages, they are different. Please read a good book/tutorial on C. Basically, `=` works by assigning the value in the right operand to the lvalue in the left

Comment: Erase the word "equals" from your vocabulary. Now, ever single `=` you see in your code should be pronounced "takes the value of". Now, read your `swap` function using that vernacular and say it to yourself.

Comment: Either you skipped the basic lessons of your course or you are in urgent need of a better course. A C textbook would also answer this easily.

Comment: @WhozCraig Now that the question is reopened I can't wait to upvote the answer which contains your convincing way of reading `=`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not the same thing. The operator `=` modifies the left operand so that it gets the same value as the right operand. It is called *assignment*.

This snippet can illustrate it:

```
int x=3, y=5;
printf("Before assignment: x: %d y: %d\n", x, y);
x=y;
printf("After assignment: x: %d y: %d\n", x, y);
```

It will print this:

```
Before assignment: x: 3 y: 5
After assignment: x: 5 y: 5
```

If you switch `x=y` to `y=x` you would get:

```
Before assignment: x: 3 y: 5
After assignment: x: 3 y: 3
```